# Error: Unknown component analytics:reportChart

Tags: visualforce, analytics

What am I missing from the report chart tag? What else is needed? Looks ok based on [Release notes on report charts documentation.](http://docs.releasenotes.salesforce.com/en-us/spring14/release-notes/rn_analytics_vf_charts.htm)

```
<apex:page standardController="Account" extensions="AccountTeamChecker" rendered="{!renderELEMENT}">

    <analytics:reportChart reportId="00OU0000001rGcq"></analytics:reportChart>

</apex:page>
```

Produces the error in the post title:
Error: Unknown component analytics:reportChart
ID is a valid report id. I am not even trying to use a field filter yet.

Comment: Is the API version of the page 29.0 or above?

Comment: Wow, yes, that's it. I thought I had checked, I had a related Apex class involved and I checked that but not the page. Thanks. Ugh.

Answer (score 1):

`<analytics:reportChart>` is only available in API version 29.0 and higher.